# Hide Status Bar during Facebook Login Dialog

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

My app is fullscreen and hides the title bar fine with

```
<application
   android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

However, during a Facebook SDK login session, without the Facebook app install, it pops up a dialog with internal browser and shows the status bar. How can I keep the status bar hidden even during Facebook login?

```
    Session.OpenRequest openRequest = new Session.OpenRequest(activity).setPermissions(permissions).setCallback(callback);
    Session session = new Session.Builder(activity).build(); 
    if (SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED.equals(session.getState()) || allowLoginUI) {
        Session.setActiveSession(session);
        session.openForRead(openRequest);
        return session;
    }
```

[image: Imgur]

I also tried setting the theme directly on the Facebook LoginActivity, but that didn't work:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
         />
```

Using Facebook Android SDK 3.5, and Android 4.2.2.

Comment: Did you find any solution @Chloe?

Comment: My co-worker solved the problem, but I didn't take the time to understand it. Try the solution below, which I copied from him.

Answer (score 2):

Let me know if this helps:

> SystemUiHider.getInstance(activity, anchorView, flags).hide();

```
 * @param activity
 *            The activity whose window's system UI should be controlled by
 *            this class.
 * @param anchorView
 *            The view on which {@link View#setSystemUiVisibility(int)} will
 *            be called.
 * @param flags
 *            Either 0 or any combination of {@link #FLAG_FULLSCREEN},
 *            {@link #FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION}, and
 *            {@link #FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN_OLDER_DEVICES}.
 */
```

---

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Build;
import android.view.View;

/**
 * A utility class that helps with showing and hiding system UI such as the
 * status bar and navigation/system bar. This class uses backward-compatibility
 * techniques described in <a href=
 * "http://developer.android.com/training/backward-compatible-ui/index.html">
 * Creating Backward-Compatible UIs</a> to ensure that devices running any
 * version of ndroid OS are supported. More specifically, there are separate
 * implementations of this abstract class: for newer devices,
 * {@link #getInstance} will return a {@link SystemUiHiderHoneycomb} instance,
 * while on older devices {@link #getInstance} will return a
 * {@link SystemUiHiderBase} instance.
 * <p>
 * For more on system bars, see <a href=
 * "http://developer.android.com/design/get-started/ui-overview.html#system-bars"
 * > System Bars</a>.
 * 
 * @see android.view.View#setSystemUiVisibility(int)
 * @see android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams#FLAG_FULLSCREEN
 */
public abstract class SystemUiHider {
    /**
     * When this flag is set, the
     * {@link android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams#FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN}
     * flag will be set on older devices, making the status bar "float" on top
     * of the activity layout. This is most useful when there are no controls at
     * the top of the activity layout.
     * <p>
     * This flag isn't used on newer devices because the <a
     * href="http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html">action
     * bar</a>, the most important structural element of an Android app, should
     * be visible and not obscured by the system UI.
     */
    public static final int FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN_OLDER_DEVICES = 0x1;

    /**
     * When this flag is set, {@link #show()} and {@link #hide()} will toggle
     * the visibility of the status bar. If there is a navigation bar, show and
     * hide will toggle low profile mode.
     */
    public static final int FLAG_FULLSCREEN = 0x2;

    /**
     * When this flag is set, {@link #show()} and {@link #hide()} will toggle
     * the visibility of the navigation bar, if it's present on the device and
     * the device allows hiding it. In cases where the navigation bar is present
     * but cannot be hidden, show and hide will toggle low profile mode.
     */
    public static final int FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION = FLAG_FULLSCREEN | 0x4;

    /**
     * The activity associated with this UI hider object.
     */
    protected Activity mActivity;

    /**
     * The view on which {@link View#setSystemUiVisibility(int)} will be called.
     */
    protected View mAnchorView;

    /**
     * The current UI hider flags.
     * 
     * @see #FLAG_FULLSCREEN
     * @see #FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
     * @see #FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN_OLDER_DEVICES
     */
    protected int mFlags;

    /**
     * The current visibility callback.
     */
    protected OnVisibilityChangeListener mOnVisibilityChangeListener = sDummyListener;

    /**
     * Creates and returns an instance of {@link SystemUiHider} that is
     * appropriate for this device. The object will be either a
     * {@link SystemUiHiderBase} or {@link SystemUiHiderHoneycomb} depending on
     * the device.
     * 
     * @param activity
     *            The activity whose window's system UI should be controlled by
     *            this class.
     * @param anchorView
     *            The view on which {@link View#setSystemUiVisibility(int)} will
     *            be called.
     * @param flags
     *            Either 0 or any combination of {@link #FLAG_FULLSCREEN},
     *            {@link #FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION}, and
     *            {@link #FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN_OLDER_DEVICES}.
     */
    public static SystemUiHider getInstance(Activity activity, View anchorView,
            int flags) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            return new SystemUiHiderHoneycomb(activity, anchorView, flags);
        } else {
            return new SystemUiHiderBase(activity, anchorView, flags);
        }
    }

    protected SystemUiHider(Activity activity, View anchorView, int flags) {
        mActivity = activity;
        mAnchorView = anchorView;
        mFlags = flags;
    }

    /**
     * Sets up the system UI hider. Should be called from
     * {@link Activity#onCreate}.
     */
    public abstract void setup();

    /**
     * Returns whether or not the system UI is visible.
     */
    public abstract boolean isVisible();

    /**
     * Hide the system UI.
     */
    public abstract void hide();

    /**
     * Show the system UI.
     */
    public abstract void show();

    /**
     * Toggle the visibility of the system UI.
     */
    public void toggle() {
        if (isVisible()) {
            hide();
        } else {
            show();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Registers a callback, to be triggered when the system UI visibility
     * changes.
     */
    public void setOnVisibilityChangeListener(
            OnVisibilityChangeListener listener) {
        if (listener == null) {
            listener = sDummyListener;
        }

        mOnVisibilityChangeListener = listener;
    }

    /**
     * A dummy no-op callback for use when there is no other listener set.
     */
    private static OnVisibilityChangeListener sDummyListener = new OnVisibilityChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onVisibilityChange(boolean visible) {
        }
    };

    /**
     * A callback interface used to listen for system UI visibility changes.
     */
    public interface OnVisibilityChangeListener {
        /**
         * Called when the system UI visibility has changed.
         * 
         * @param visible
         *            True if the system UI is visible.
         */
        public void onVisibilityChange(boolean visible);
    }
}
```

---

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;

/**
 * A base implementation of {@link SystemUiHider}. Uses APIs available in all
 * API levels to show and hide the status bar.
 */
public class SystemUiHiderBase extends SystemUiHider {
    /**
     * Whether or not the system UI is currently visible. This is a cached value
     * from calls to {@link #hide()} and {@link #show()}.
     */
    private boolean mVisible = true;

    /**
     * Constructor not intended to be called by clients. Use
     * {@link SystemUiHider#getInstance} to obtain an instance.
     */
    protected SystemUiHiderBase(Activity activity, View anchorView, int flags) {
        super(activity, anchorView, flags);
    }

    @Override
    public void setup() {
        if ((mFlags & FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN_OLDER_DEVICES) == 0) {
            mActivity.getWindow().setFlags(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN
                            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN
                            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isVisible() {
        return mVisible;
    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {
        if ((mFlags & FLAG_FULLSCREEN) != 0) {
            mActivity.getWindow().setFlags(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        }
        mOnVisibilityChangeListener.onVisibilityChange(false);
        mVisible = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        if ((mFlags & FLAG_FULLSCREEN) != 0) {
            mActivity.getWindow().setFlags(0,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        }
        mOnVisibilityChangeListener.onVisibilityChange(true);
        mVisible = true;
    }
}
```

---

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Build;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;

/**
 * An API 11+ implementation of {@link SystemUiHider}. Uses APIs available in
 * Honeycomb and later (specifically {@link View#setSystemUiVisibility(int)}) to
 * show and hide the system UI.
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public class SystemUiHiderHoneycomb extends SystemUiHiderBase {
    /**
     * Flags for {@link View#setSystemUiVisibility(int)} to use when showing the
     * system UI.
     */
    private int mShowFlags;

    /**
     * Flags for {@link View#setSystemUiVisibility(int)} to use when hiding the
     * system UI.
     */
    private int mHideFlags;

    /**
     * Flags to test against the first parameter in
     * {@link android.view.View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener#onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int)}
     * to determine the system UI visibility state.
     */
    private int mTestFlags;

    /**
     * Whether or not the system UI is currently visible. This is cached from
     * {@link android.view.View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener}.
     */
    private boolean mVisible = true;

    /**
     * Constructor not intended to be called by clients. Use
     * {@link SystemUiHider#getInstance} to obtain an instance.
     */
    protected SystemUiHiderHoneycomb(Activity activity, View anchorView,
            int flags) {
        super(activity, anchorView, flags);

        mShowFlags = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE;
        mHideFlags = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE;
        mTestFlags = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE;

        if ((mFlags & FLAG_FULLSCREEN) != 0) {
            // If the client requested fullscreen, add flags relevant to hiding
            // the status bar. Note that some of these constants are new as of
            // API 16 (Jelly Bean). It is safe to use them, as they are inlined
            // at compile-time and do nothing on pre-Jelly Bean devices.
            mShowFlags |= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN;
            mHideFlags |= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        }

        if ((mFlags & FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION) != 0) {
            // If the client requested hiding navigation, add relevant flags.
            mShowFlags |= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION;
            mHideFlags |= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;
            mTestFlags |= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;
        }
    }

    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    @Override
    public void setup() {
        mAnchorView
                .setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(mSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener);
    }

    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    @Override
    public void hide() {
        mAnchorView.setSystemUiVisibility(mHideFlags);
    }

    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    @Override
    public void show() {
        mAnchorView.setSystemUiVisibility(mShowFlags);
    }

    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    @Override
    public boolean isVisible() {
        return mVisible;
    }

    private View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener mSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener = new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int vis) {
            // Test against mTestFlags to see if the system UI is visible.
            if ((vis & mTestFlags) != 0) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                    // Pre-Jelly Bean, we must manually hide the action bar
                    // and use the old window flags API.
                    mActivity.getActionBar().hide();
                    mActivity.getWindow().setFlags(
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
                }

                // Trigger the registered listener and cache the visibility
                // state.
                mOnVisibilityChangeListener.onVisibilityChange(false);
                mVisible = false;

            } else {
                mAnchorView.setSystemUiVisibility(mShowFlags);
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                    // Pre-Jelly Bean, we must manually show the action bar
                    // and use the old window flags API.
                    mActivity.getActionBar().show();
                    mActivity.getWindow().setFlags(0,
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
                }

                // Trigger the registered listener and cache the visibility
                // state.
                mOnVisibilityChangeListener.onVisibilityChange(true);
                mVisible = true;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Hi Chloe thanks for your answer.When I tried to use `SystemUiHider.getInstance().hide()`, `getInstance()`method requires 3 properties. I can put in two of them bu I don't know what `int flags` is. Can you help me with this?

Comment: This sound extremely convoluted... for such a simple fix.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to get a reference to the dialog and then simply use, as far as I can tell.

```
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Comment: Ok sounds easy, but how do you get a reference to the dialog? The Facebook SDK generates that dialog internally and displays it when you try to open a session and no user is logged in (and the Facebook app is not installed).